# Visual Studio - Collapsing Derived Class Hides Inherited Class

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2015, ide

Is there a setting or option somewhere that changes the collapse behavior for classes so that derived classes show their parents?  It's dumb, and maybe a bit pedantic, but when you have classes that derive in multiple levels and branches, it's a slight annoyance not to be able to see them at a glance.

Expanded:

[image: Expanded]

Collapsed:

[image: Collapsed]